# CSS 50% top with transform -50% behaving weird in Edge

Tags: css

I have some images that are placed 50% from the top of the container like this:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Works perfectly fine as normal on every browser on my mac and chrome on windows, but for some reason MS Edge isn't honouring any of this properly; it seems to be totally ignoring the "top" parameter and just applying the transform.

So i thought well if i take out "tansform: translateY(-50%)" and leave in -webkit-transform then chrome and safari should be ok with that - but for some reason Edge is also reading the -webkit-transform property??

Here are screenshots of the correct version, VS edge (also happens in IE11):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity asking, Why you are setting `top: 50%` and then canceling it with `transform: translateY(-50%)`?

Comment: @VivekrajKR It is a trick to vertically centre the element. They do not cancel each other out since `top: 50%` and `translateY(50%)` are not equivalent.

Comment: @VivekrajKR because top uses the top edge of the photo to position the centre, not the centre of the image. Just typical of Microsoft to go against the normal behaviour.

Comment: We haven't needed those vendor prefixes in many years.

Comment: @GlenElkins I don't know why Edge behaves as you describe, but perhaps a flex-box approach would be simpler: https://jsfiddle.net/xeu4jfv6/1/

Comment: @Turnip in this case, no flex box wouldn't be the best option otherwise would have done it like that

Comment: @GlenElkins Turnip, Understood. If your requirement is to vertically center the item, I'd recommend going with flexbox solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would scrap this method all together and use flex. It will do all the hard work for you:

Your question should come with a CodePen or Fiddle of some kind so I can't test it and give you a nicely packaged answer, but for now try:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Things you can play around with are 'align-items' this is how the boxes within the row (specified in 'flex-direction' which can also be column) vertically align. You can also change 'justify-content' which is the horizontal spacing of the elements. You most likely are wanting this to be set to 'space-evenly'.

This won't be a miracle fix as I can't directly apply it to your example.